# Using imagePickerController with swift 2

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the following function to grab photos from  a users photo library, and I am getting the error:

> Objective-C method `'imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editinginfo` conflicts with optional requirement in protocol `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    print("Image Selected")

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    importedImage.image = image

}
```

Can anyone tell me how to modify the function to conform to swift 2.0 optional requirements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 2.0 version:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        // you code
    }
```

If you use XCode 7, you can just delete this func, and re-type it and allow XCode to autocomplete it using the new syntax.

**Note**, this protocol requirement has been deprecated, use this instead:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // your code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the image before dismissing the view controller.